# angularFire startAt querying and binding deletes new data

Tags: firebase, angularfire

The application shows work-shifts for certain time-period. firebaseConn.getShifts is the API-function to get the shiftData for the given time period.

versions:
firebase: 2.0.6
angularFire: 0.9.0 (confirmed with 0.8.2 also)

This is my firebase schema:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
.factory('watchers', function(bunch-of-dependencies) {
  var unbindShifts = function() {};
  var inited = false;
  var shifts = {};
```

... some irrelevant code in between ...

```
  function initShifts() {
     unbindShifts();
     shifts.object = firebaseConn.getShifts( false, from, to, $scope );

     $scope.shifts = shifts.object;
     shifts.object.$bindTo($scope, "shifts").then(function(unbind) {
        unbindShifts = unbind;
     });
  }
```

The firebase-queries (that have worked fine before adding the unbind / bind and possibly time-based querying might cause issues too):

```
  firebaseConn.getShifts = function(asArray, from, to, scope) {
     return cacheRequest(FBURL + "shifts", asArray, [from, to]);
  };

  function cacheRequest(url, asArray, limits) {
     var type = asArray ? "array" : "object";
     var startAt = limits ? limits[0] : undefined;
     var endAt = limits ? limits[1] : undefined;
     var retObj, FBRef;

     cached[url] = cached[url] || {};

     /* If there are limits-parameters we don't cache at all atm. Since those queries should be checked differently than static urls */
     if(!limits && cached[url][type]) {
        FBRef = cached[url][type];
     } else {
        FBRef = cached[url][type] = createFBRef(url, startAt, endAt);
     }

     if(asArray) {
        retObj = FBRef.$asArray();
     } else {
        retObj = FBRef.$asObject();
     }

     return retObj;
  }

  function createFBRef(resourceURL, startAt, endAt) {
     var modifiedObject = $firebase( createRef( resourceURL ).orderByKey().startAt(startAt).endAt(endAt) );

     return modifiedObject;
  }

  function createRef(resourceURL) {
     return new Firebase( resourceURL );
  }
```

Now I have located the problem to be with the query limiting. If the from and to Dates are undefined, this works without problems. But I need to be able to limit the amount of data, since loading many years of workshift-data, to show a weeks time, won't be good :).

The actual problem is not displaying and fetching the data, everything works fine, it's related to the times and re-binding.

If I do any changes to e.g. "20150115"-table. For example I add another "groups"-child there. When i unbind and rebind, the whole "20150115"-table gets deleted and this holds true only to the latest changes. If I add multiple child to different dates e.g. "20150113", "20150114", "20150115" and the latest change is in "20150115" and then I unbind + re-bind another time from firebase, all the other root-paths will stay as they are, but the latest change in "20150115" will make the whole tree deleted.

I hope I make myself clear, so for safety I try to explain it again in simpler way.
- Changes to 1. "20150113", 2. "20150114", 3. "20150115" through the app.
- Changing timeline from UI causes: unbind + re-bind
- As a side-effect the whole "20150114" tree gets deleted.

The problem is somehow related to advanced querying with orderByKey().startAt(startAt).endAt(endAt) and binding.

Also for additional info. The data which is added through the UI gets added to the firebase database, but when the re-binding happens, the data is deleted from the database. Specifically on rebind, unbinding causes no issues, if I delay rebinding with timeout.

**EDIT:**

I have found the source of the actual issue. After the new binding is in place and everything seems to be in order, there is an angular watch event that kicks in. The event tries to save the last change user made before re-binding.

So if I have and active timeline for december (20141201 - 20141230) and I change "20141225"-data. Then change the timeline to 20150101 - 20150130, causing unbind and rebind (or manually fetching new data). There will be an event, after the binding has been done and everything seems to be in order, trying to save 20141225 data to either the new timeline (20150101 - 20150130) or the old one, not sure which one. This causes the firebase to actually delete the whole 20141225-tree, instead of saving the data.

Comment: Hey Hachi. It sounds like you're working on a cool application and the data structure looks reasonable for the use-cases you describe. But I find it difficult to understand your problem through all the text. Can you write a minimal piece of code that reproduces your problem? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey Frank, sure. Sorry if I lack good explanation skills. Here is a plunkr I managed to generate: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nk62dYfdiFvqkb9fT06F?p=preview . So push "addNew", see the new entry added, push "forward" and then "backward" and the entry has been deleted from firebase, for some reason.

Comment: When I take those steps, the new data remains in Firebase. As you can easily test by `new Firebase("https://your.firebaseio.com").once('value', function(s) { console.log(JSON.stringify(s.val())); })`. But you're missing a `$scope.$apply()` in your `setDays`. I'll write up a quick answer and some pointers to related questions.

Answer (score 1):

The new data makes it into your Firebase fine, which you can see by either checking your Firebase dashboard or by running a quick snippet like this in your browser's dev console:

```
new Firebase("https://firebaseurl").once('value', function(s) { console.log(s.val()); })
```

The data even makes it back into your application. The only problem is that Angular doesn't know that new data has arrived, so it doesn't update the view with the new data.

Normally AngularFire's `$asObject` and `$asArray` methods take care of notifying AngularJS when new data arrives from Firebase. But since you are constantly creating new queries, you'll have to take care of that yourself.

There are a few ways to signal the new data to AngularJS and I'm definitely not an expert on which one is best. But if you add `$scope.$apply();` to your `setDays` function it works:

```
function setDays(ref) {
  var FBRange = setFBRange(ref, from, to);
  var days;

  unbindDays();

  days = $firebase(FBRange).$asObject();
  $scope.days = days;

  days.$bindTo($scope, "days").then(function(unbind) {
      unbindDays = unbind;
      // As a result of the new binding entry gets mysteriously deleted from firebase
   });

   $scope.$apply(); // Tell AngularJS about the new data, so that it updates the view

  function setFBRange(ref, from, to) {
    return ref.orderByKey().startAt(""+from).endAt(from + to + "");
  }
}
```

Updated Plunkr with this change (and some others to help in debugging): http://plnkr.co/edit/YZtkzUNtjQUCcw4xb2mj?p=preview

Comment: I tried the plnkr and thank you! But unfortunately it's still not working :). You missed the actual problem I'm having. If you would see the firebase-dashboard it would be easier to show, but... I emptied the firebase DB now... you can see the issue, by trying to add PERSISTENT data to the database. I mean: push addNew in different "dates" and try to make the data stay in the database and in the application after forward:ing and backward:ing. It gets deleted for some reason. Though randomly it stays.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the exact same problem to the plunker now. But have failed so far. I realized the issue at the original plunker might be the same, or it might be different. At present I have a slightly different issue than at my own app: http://plnkr.co/edit/MHR4AK?p=preview, but my original problem was persistent, this one is more random. It is also possible the problem is related to angular and scope.apply or what not. But my expertise on digest / apply inner workings is unfortunately limited too. And the original problem indicated firebase-related.

Comment: Even with the present plunker, there is clear issue with how it works and I'm not sure where the problem lies. I could go around the problem with manually saving the data, instead of 3-way databinding. But I'd still really like to get this issue solved :/.

Comment: Hey, one more comment. I made a new plunker. Which seems to work fine in 3-way. The only difference is that this is manually linked, not binded with angularfire. http://plnkr.co/edit/YMTw2M?p=preview ... works persistent, while re-binding seems to not work correctly, or I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed missing something. I actually missed it at first too: if a new item would fall into your existing query, then it would automatically be synchronized to the client by Firebase and to the Angular view by AngularFire. But in your case, you are creating a new query. The new query will get the data for the new date. But that data will not be synchronized to the view, since you didn't bind *the new query* to the scope. That's why you have to do that manually.

Comment: Just thought to mention. I don't know if you noticed I edited the original post and solved my original problem, though it's still a mystery what the actual problem was. When I bind it manually, what happens is that an event of the last made change triggers AFTER I have queried new data and manually bound it to view and to database. I actually solve it now so, that before submitting data to firebase I check is it a valid date, compared to the present active dates. Basically is the data to be inserted out-of-bounds, if it is, discard the insert. Thank you a lot for the help still!

Comment: I noticed that the only issue in firebase is that you can insert outside the fetched query range, but it doesn't get inserted correctly. Basically this plunker should explain it: http://plnkr.co/edit/nMZ9eT?p=preview . If you insert something -> push forward and "insert old", it will overwrite the old data from that timeline, eventhough it shouldn't. I would consider that as un-intentional feature or some sort of bug :).

Comment: AngularFire at that stage hasn't synchronized the data, so it ends up replacing the existing data. If you want to use three-way sync to update the data, you should ensure the data is synchronized. Alternative, you can just update it using the regular Firebase API: `new Firebase("https://your.firebaseio.com").child(from-2).child('node').update({ insert: 1});` worked without problems just now.

Comment: Thanks you a lot Frank! In the end I didn't get it working as I would've wanted, but using the basic Firebase-commands I get at least peace of my mind for a while :). I guess I should later go through angularFire and firebase codebase a bit more to really wrap my head around what happens.